# Returning object property from array

Tags: javascript

I'm using the filter method to return an object property when a value is true. However my filter method doesn't stop iterating over the array when it finds the true value so iterates over all the elements and returns a null value.

I want to break out of the array filter once the condition is true.

This is what I've done:

```
array.filter((v)=>{
  var a = v.id === x ? v.collection : null
  console.log(a)
  return a
})
```

I have three elements in the array and my `console.log` prints out `'music', 'null', 'null'`. I want it to break when it is 'music'.

Comment: Use find instead of filter

Comment: The [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function expects its callback to return a *boolean*.  It's designed to return a *new array* with certain elements ***filtered out***.

Comment: See [MDN: *Array.prototype.find*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterates all elements, [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the wanted or `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the first matching element, you can use `find` rather than `filter`.

It will return the first matching element, stop iterating, and return the match.